# German idiom similar to "to put the whole matter into a nutshell"?

Tags: english-to-german

Does similar figure of speech exist in German or should one translate *to put the whole matter into a nutshell* literally?

> Ein Fazit ziehen

seems to make sense, but seems to be better used as a heading with colon:

> Fazit:

What would be the correct term to mark the beginning of a conclusion in German?

Comment: `Fazit` alone would be enough..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's this short phrase

> Um es kurz zu sagen: ...

or

> Um es kurz zu machen: ...

Also,

> Langer Rede kurzer Sinn: ...

If you can sum it up in one word, you could also use

> Mit einem Wort: ...

Comment: And then there's always *kurz und gut* or *kurzum*.

Comment: And all of those are *usually* used right after going on for far too long on a topic. And more often than not, the explanation that follows is far too long as well ;-)